# VMware synced folder speed on Windows host?

Tags: vagrant, vmware, virtualization

I am using Vagrant with VirtualBox at the moment. Unfortunately despite having SSDs the synced folder speed is too horrible to handle loading M2. I am using SMB, but have also tried to setup NFS server. Overall it did seem to improve, but not by much.

VMware has been praised as having "naturally fast synced folders" or something like that. Something that with Windows you would otherwise have to hack to get NFS working. Yet recently I also found some reports that their synced folders are slow too. So which is it? Does anyone have any experience? Especially how VMware would compare to Windows with NFS working. And does VMware suffer the same issues NFS does (max path of 255 chars)?

Vagrant does not support trial VMware. So in order to actually test it personally you not only have to buy the Vagrant plugin for VMware, but also the VMware product. I would rather only spend this money if I knew the trial at least was going to be worth it. Though you could get your money back - you still have to part with it.

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, you may get better results on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com.

Comment: It actually is since developers (that's programmers to you) use these kind of environments to run their code.

Comment: per [vagrant site](https://www.vagrantup.com/vmware/index.html#buy-now) _We do not offer a trial mechanism at this time, but we do offer a 30-day, no questions asked, 100% money-back guarantee. If you are not satisfied with the product, contact us within 30 days and you will receive a full refund_

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this superuser post about speeds https://superuser.com/questions/1025864/how-to-speed-up-vmware-shared-folders where they also discuss some benchmarks

Comment: Thank you. In the end I have found that everything is slow and that is that. The NAT idea was interesting and I did try, however you cannot disable NAT with Vagrant. So far I have resigned myself to using Vagrant only on light projects and will go with Laragon for heavier ones and thus run them on the host (multi PHP version support is required). Running on Windows will probably introduce other problems, but you got to do what you got to do.